# How do I change the background color of a Table using code? WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

I don't know how to use the
`- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color`

Comment: Do you need to use code?  Or can you use the storyboard?

Comment: I need to understand how to use the method - (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color. Changing the color of cells is very different from TableView

Comment: Please see my edit to my answer.  Labels have no setBackgroundColor, but Groups do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a class to act as a row controller.  You can have an IBOutlet to your label, but you need an IBOutlet to a Group to have the setBackgroundColor method.  You then loop through your rows in your main interface controller, cast them as your row controller class, and then can access the Group and assign it a color with setBackgroundColor.  You can assign from a model or an array of UIColor objects.  I haven’t done it myself but, based on reading code, it should work.

See https://www.raywenderlich.com/288-watchos-4-tutorial-part-2-tables for some code.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that you just needed to create an IBOutlet var _ : WKInterfaceGroup! in the NSObject class and just bind it to the table

Comment: Great!  Glad you got it.